# A Web Part or Web Form Control on this Page cannot be displayed or imported. The type is not registered as safe. Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I'm getting stuck with the above mentioned error. I have successfully deployed the webpart in 3 different ways, throgh stsadm, through Powershell (add-spsolution, install-spsolution) and via Central Administration.
The Webpart is .wsp which ran without any problems in Sharepoint 2007. I have changed the `<safe control>`entries in the web.config.

```
  <SafeControl Assembly="TimeRecordingWP, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" Namespace="TimeRecordingWP" TypeName="*" Safe="True" AllowRemoteDesigner="True" SafeAgainstScript="true" />
  <SafeControl Assembly="TimeRecordingWP, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" Namespace="TimeRecordingWP.Controls" TypeName="*" Safe="True" AllowRemoteDesigner="True" SafeAgainstScript="true" />
  <SafeControl Assembly="TimeRecordingWP, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" Namespace="TimeRecordingWP.Util" TypeName="*" Safe="True" AllowRemoteDesigner="True" SafeAgainstScript="true" />
  <SafeControl Assembly="TimeRecordingWP, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" Namespace="TimeRecordingWP.Dao" TypeName="*" Safe="True" AllowRemoteDesigner="True" SafeAgainstScript="true" />
```

I have changed the `<trust>`parameter to Full but no success. Neither the Preview in Webpartcatalog->all webparts nor the webpart will work showing the message named in the title of this post.
I'm pretty lost.

Thank's in advance..

Answer (score 7):

I managed to fix the problem.

My case was:

- Created new Visual Web Part with Visual Studio 2010
- Copied some stuff from similar project
- Renamed some properties to project-specific names
- Got this error when tried to add the webpart to a page.

Thing that fixed my issue:
Changed Namespace value of SafeControl in SharePointProjectItem.spdata (hidden file) to match the actual namespace I was using

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Rene.
I gave some thoughts to the same matter few days ago. The problem was happened when I created not an empty project and rename some properties in it to more sensible.
Unfortunately, I couldn't find the reason of this problem. But I resolved it by creating an empty sharepoint project and adding the necessary items in it.